# Codeigniter: share session with subdomain & sess_time_to_update

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

It was a lot of questions how to share CI native sessions between subdomains or domain & subdomain.

Just some of them: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881092/subdomain-overwiting-codeigniter-session), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455149/php-sessions-across-multiple-domains-not-subdomains), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783595/codeigniter-session-cookie-domain)

Everybody says that we should define `$config['cookie_domain']` like this

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".example.com";
```

It seems to be correct answer, but... subdomain drops data on update (the value `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;`) on both domains. After the `sess_time_to_update` is expired all data get droped.

*Additional info*:

- CodeIgniter ver. 2.1.4
- Subdomain & domain use the same files (alias).
- $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 5):

i usually would do:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'asd';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0; //24hours -> 8640
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'db_table';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3000000000;

$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
```

Comment: Actualy it would work, but don't you think that large sess_time_to_update can lead to issues?

Comment: @Yevgen what you mean ? :)

Comment: I suppose it can lead to extra records to DB and irrelevant data in a current user's session.

Comment: @Yevgen well try it with or without ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's the only solution that really WORKED for me.